# Redefining based on original definition

Tags: macros

For example, there's a command `\x` and another `\y`. I want to redefine `\x` so that it becomes its original self followed by `\y`. I found that directly using `\renewcommand\x{\x\y}` doesn't work because it puts LaTeX into some endless recursive loop and resulting in

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]
```

So perhaps I need something that can hold the definition of old `\x` but will not expand into it.

Comment: add `\let\originalx\x` before your `\renewcommand\x{\originalx\y}`

Comment: @koleygr perhaps, or perhaps that will loop as well.

Comment: Please tell us more about the propreties of `\x` and `\y`. E.g., do they take atguments?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle At least it didn't on my computer.

Comment: it  will, depending on the definition of `\x`. Use `\NewCommandCopy` not `\let`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic primitive for saving a definition is `\let` but this has to be used with care (or better said, not used) with higher level latex commands as often a command `\x` just has definition `\def\x{\protect\xinternal}` and `\let` just saves the top level so your renewcommand defines `\xinternal` in terms of itself.

LaTeX has a `\NewCommandCopy` that does a "deep copy" of the internal macros that  make up commands that have been defined by any of the standard latex definition forms:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\x[1][hmm]{#1!}

\begin{document}

\x[A]

%\let\originalx\x % this would loop
\NewCommandCopy\originalx\x

\renewcommand\x[1][oops]{\originalx[#1] ??}

\x[B]

\end{document}
```

However a more controlled way to modify functionality in a way that allows multiple packages to adjust the same command is to use the generic command hooks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\x[1][hmm]{#1!}

\begin{document}

\x[A]


\AddToHook{cmd/x/after}{???}


\x[B]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it that LaTeX generates a hook which you can access by ```cmd/x/after``` like method for every macro?

Comment: @youthdoo yes (so long as your latex is new enough)

Comment: Is there anything similar to ```\AddToHook{cmd/x/after}{???}``` that can add before the command? ```\AddToHook{cmd/x/before}{???}``` doesn't seem right.

Comment: @youthdoo as you suggest. see  `texdoc ltcmdhooks-doc`

Answer (score 2):

If you use a helpful class, it will store the original definition for you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\x}{x}
\newcommand{\y}{y}

\renewcommand<>{\x}{\beameroriginal{\x}\y}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\x
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you don't use such a nice and well behaved class, you can use the `beamerarticle` package to make this available in other classes as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\newcommand{\x}{x}
\newcommand{\y}{y}

\renewcommand<>{\x}{\beameroriginal{\x}\y}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\x
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand<>{\x}{x}
\newcommand{\y}{y}

\renewcommand<>{\x}{\beameroriginal{\x}\y}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\x
\end{frame}

\end{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You like breaking stuff, don't you? :)

Comment: beamer could/should use `\NewCommandCopy` not `\let` to set up `\beameroriginal`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! I'll look into that

Comment: This is interesting. Why would ```beamer``` provide this feature?

Comment: @youthdoo ... beamer redefines a lot of macros to make them overlay aware. It is convenient to have the original version still available to use it in the new definition.

Comment: What is this `<>`?

Comment: @dedded the `<>` is special syntax beamer for overlay specifications, e.g. if something should only be revealed on a later slide.