# Redefine overlay-aware beamer command using xparse

Tags: beamer, macros, xparse

Suppose to want the `\texttt` command accept two optional arguments **with a default value** before and after the mandatory one, in order to specify anything (here spaces) that should be prepended or appended to the teletyped text (see disclaimer).

Having two optional arguments made me think to `xparse`. This might be a valid approach:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,xparse}

\NewCommandCopy{\OldTexttt}{\texttt}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\texttt}{O{\,} m O{\,}}{#1\OldTexttt{#2}#3\null}

\begin{document}
    --\OldTexttt{Hello}--

    --\texttt{Hello}--

    --\textcolor{red}{\texttt{Hello}}--

    --\textcolor{blue}{\texttt[\quad]{Hello}[\qquad]}--
\end{document}
```

However, using the new `\texttt` inside `\textcolor` breaks down using the same code in a beamer presentation. My guess is that this is because the `beamer` class redefines the `\texttt` command to make it overlay-aware as

```
\renewcommand<>{\texttt}{\only#1{\beameroriginal{\texttt}}}
```

but I am not really understanding what exactly happens under the hood in the following **not-compiling** code and, in particular, what is triggering the `Paragraph ended before \texttt was complete. \end{frame}` error. Can someone explain what is failing and why?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewCommandCopy{\OldTexttt}{\texttt}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\texttt}{O{\,} m O{\,}}{#1\OldTexttt{#2}#3\null}

% My workaround at the moment:
% \RenewDocumentCommand{\texttt}{O{\,} m O{\,}}{#1{\ttfamily#2}#3\null}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}
        --\OldTexttt{Hello}--
    
        --\texttt{Hello}--
        
        --\textcolor{red}{\texttt{Hello}}--
        
        --\textcolor{blue}{\texttt[\quad]{Hello}[\qquad]}--
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now, getting away from the "two-optional-arguments-approach" (which I would still like to understand), I thought that one could also add a fixed space (e.g. `\,`) around the teletyped text and then define a new command to change it. However, I failed to modify the beamer re-definition above, in order to add `\,` space **after** the teletyped text. Is this possible? How? As side remark, I found that `\beameroriginal` [is still using](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670533/redefining-based-on-original-definition#comment1666777_670551) `\let` instead of `\NewCommandCopy` to store the original command, but I am not sure whether this is relevant here.

#### Bonus question

Is `\null` a good idea to respect the spaces after the teletyped text? In the *List of internal LATEX2e Macros* (`texdoc macros2e`) it seemed fine to me, but I am not that experienced to really judge.

#### Disclaimer

This is more an academical question to understand better LaTeX mechanisms than a real need. I know that `\texttt[A]{xxx}[B]` is simply equivalent to `A\texttt{xxx}B`, but here the point is to (i) have almost always used default values still having full flexibility when needed and, more importantly (ii) understand/learn a bit more.